# Get appropriate objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I created an array like below:

```
arrayObject = [{one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5"}, 
               {one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5"}];
```

How can I get/filter that array to had arrayObject only with "one", "two" and "five" element like below:

```
arrayObject = [{one: "1", two: "2", five: "5"}, 
               {one: "1", two: "2",  five: "5"}];
```

What's the best way to do it ?

Comment: Are you wanting to get objects that only have them 3 keys or change the objects to just have them 3 keys?

Comment: Are you wanting to get an array object as per the key bases or value bases?

Comment: I want to change the arrya to have 3 keys.

Comment: `arrayObject.map(({ three, four, ...rest }) => rest)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could map only the wanted properties ba destructuring an getting a new object from the variables.

```js
var array = [{ one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5" }, { one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5" }],
    result = array.map(({ one, two, five }) => ({ one, two, five }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function extractObjectWithKeys(objects, keys) {
  return objects.reduce((acc, elem) => {
    let newObj = {};
    let filteredKeys = Object.keys(elem).filter(k => keys.includes(k));
    filteredKeys.forEach(key => {
      newObj[key] = elem[key];
    });
    return acc.concat(newObj);
  }, []);
}

const arrayObject = [
  {one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5"}, 
  {one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5"}
];

//Usage:
extractObjectWithKeys(arrayObject, ["one", "two", "five"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of items you wish to keep you can use `Object.fromEntries()` with `.map()`. By mapping your array of items you want to keep (here I called it `keep`) to an array of key-value pairs (ie: [`[key, value], ...]`). You can then use `Object.fromEntries()` to turn the given array into an object like so:

```js
const keep = ["one", "two", "five"];
const arrayObject = [{ one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5" }, { one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5" } ];

const res = arrayObject.map(
  obj => Object.fromEntries(keep.map(key => [key, obj[key]])
));
console.log(res);
```

Do note, `Object.fromEntries()` does have limited browser support, if you need something with a little better browser support you could use `.reduce()`
like so:

```js
const keep = ["one", "two", "five"];
const arrayObject = [{ one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5" }, { one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5" } ];
const res = arrayObject.map(
  obj => keep.map(key => [key, obj[key]]).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({...acc, [k]: v}), {})
);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map and use spread like below

```js
arrayObject = [{one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5"}, 
               {one: "1", two: "2", three: "3", four: "4", five: "5"}];
               
let filtered=arrayObject.map(a=>{

  const {three,four,...rest}=a;
  return rest;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: [he](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2284676/octohedron) knows why (his answer here was downvoted and then deleted)